# PHP & Android: Upload File not uploading the file but there are no errors

Tags: php, android, upload

I used a php script in order to upload a xml file form a device to a Server and it worked fine. However, I started to do changes and it doesnt upload the file anymore. I guess there is some error in the code.
Here is what I use:

```
<?php
$target_path  = "subida/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "El fichero ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." ha sido enviado";
} else{
 echo "Hubo un error, inténtalo de nuevo!";
}
?>
```

Comment: what exactly "doesn't work"?  what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It does not upload the file in the server folder